# ListAddapter in FragmentList

Tags: android, eclipse, android-listfragment

Why are these errors appearing?

```
04-10 17:07:57.880: E/AndroidRuntime(917): Process: com.example.programming_fragments, PID: 917
04-10 17:07:57.880: E/AndroidRuntime(917): java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
04-10 17:07:57.880: E/AndroidRuntime(917):  at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:344)
04-10 17:07:57.880: E/AndroidRuntime(917):  at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:145)
04-10 17:07:57.880: E/AndroidRuntime(917):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:925)
04-10 17:07:57.880: E/AndroidRuntime(917):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
04-10 17:07:57.880: E/AndroidRuntime(917):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-10 17:07:57.880: E/AndroidRuntime(917):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
04-10 17:07:57.880: E/AndroidRuntime(917):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
04-10 17:07:57.880: E/AndroidRuntime(917):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-10 17:07:57.880: E/AndroidRuntime(917):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-10 17:07:57.880: E/AndroidRuntime(917):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-10 17:07:57.880: E/AndroidRuntime(917):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-10 17:07:57.880: E/AndroidRuntime(917):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 17:07:57.880: E/AndroidRuntime(917):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-10 17:07:57.880: E/AndroidRuntime(917):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-10 17:07:57.880: E/AndroidRuntime(917):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-10 17:07:57.880: E/AndroidRuntime(917):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#ffeeeeee" android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical" > <ListView android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" /> </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you attach your code and xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with the layout you have set in **onCreateView**().

If you override the onCreateView in your custom **ListFragment** , you need to inflate a layout which has a ListView in it, with id **android:id="@android:id/list"**.

If you really want to have a different layout than the default one used in ListFragment , then only override the onCreateView() , else use the default layout.

This is what the code in ListFragment,. You can look at the default layout (**R.layout.list_content**) and see if you really need to override this layout

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(com.android.internal.R.layout.list_content,
            container, false);
}
```

Comment: Sir i did excacty what u said :'(

Comment: can i send u my project pleesze

Comment: Siir is very Limit i cant

Answer (score 0):

Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is android.R.id.list. So go to your xml that contains your listview and add the id so it looks something like:

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

You can, of course, have a custom list, but I am going to assume you are using a simple list adapter based on your question, so this should work for you.